# How to check flash is enabled in browser or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, modernizr

I am using jquery 1.9. Using this jQuery version how can we check the flash is enabled or not in the running browser?

Comment: You're looking for Modernizr, not jQuery. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9038034/test-whether-a-device-has-flash-enabled-modernizr-style

Comment: There isn't a reliable Modernizr detect for Flash yet - but we'd like one! See https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/48

Answer (score 4):

Try this :

```
var hasFlash = false;
try {
  var fo = new ActiveXObject('ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash');
  if(fo) hasFlash = true;
}catch(e){
if(navigator.mimeTypes ["application/x-shockwave-flash"] != undefined) 
    hasFlash = true;
}
```

OR

jqplugin: http://code.google.com/p/jqplugin/

`$.browser.flash == true`

Comment: This seems to work (good enough) for me.  We will move to Modernizer v3 when it goes public.